# MariaDB is throwing a syntax error when creating foreign key

Tags: mariadb

```
CREATE DATABASE mylaboratory;

USE mylaboratory;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Account`;

CREATE TABLE `Account` (
  `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '계정 이메일 (ID)',
  `HashedPassword` longtext NOT NULL COMMENT '계정 암호화 된 비밀번호',
  `FullName` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '계정 성명',
  `AvatarImagePath` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '/upload/Management/Profile/default-avatar.jpg' COMMENT '계정 아바타 이미지 경로',
  `Role` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'User' COMMENT '계정 역할 (Admin 또는 User)',
  `Locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '계정 잠금',
  `LoginAttempt` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '로그인 시도 횟수',
  `EmailConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '이메일 확인 여부',
  `AgreedServiceTerms` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '약관 동의 여부',
  `RegistrationToken` longtext DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '회원가입 인증 토큰',
  `ResetPasswordToken` longtext DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '비밀번호 찾기 인증 토큰',
  `Created` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000' COMMENT '계정 생성일',
  `Updated` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000' COMMENT '계정 업데이트일',
  `Message` longtext DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '계정 상태 메시지',
  `Deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '계정 삭제 여부',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Email`),
  CONSTRAINT `Accounts_check` CHECK (`Role` = 'Admin' or `Role` = 'User')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT 'MyLaboratory.Site 계정';

CREATE TABLE mylaboratory.Asset (
    Email varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '계정 이메일 (ID)',
    ProductName varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '상품명 (은행 계좌명, 증권 계좌명, 현금 등)',
    item varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '항목 (자유입출금 자산, 신탁 자산, 현금 자산, 저축성 자산, 투자성 자산, 부동산, 동산, 기타 실물 자산, 보험 자산)',
    Amount BIGINT(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '금액',
    MonetaryUnit varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '화폐 단위 (KRW, USD, ETC)',
    Created DATETIME(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '생성일',
    Updated DATETIME(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '업데이트일',
    Note varchar(255) NULL COMMENT '비고',
    Reserved0 varchar(100) NULL,
    Reserved1 varchar(100) NULL,
    Reserved2 varchar(100) NULL,
    Reserved3 varchar(100) NULL,
    Reserved4 varchar(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Email, ProductName),
    KEY Asset_FK (Email),
    CONSTRAINT Asset_FK FOREIGN KEY (Email) REFERENCES mylaboratory.Account(Email)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
COMMENT='계정 자산';
```

Error:

> Error occurred during SQL query execution
>
> SQL Error [1005] [HY000]: (conn=61) Can't create table `mylaboratory`.`asset` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I can't figure it out what is wrong in foreign key syntax.

MariaDB 10.2.38 version.

Comment: -To halfer-
Thank you for edit my article!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use two different character sets with a foreign key, they have to be the same or at least compatible

```
CREATE TABLE Asset (
    Email varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '계정 이메일 (ID)',
    ProductName varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '상품명 (은행 계좌명, 증권 계좌명, 현금 등)',
    item varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '항목 (자유입출금 자산, 신탁 자산, 현금 자산, 저축성 자산, 투자성 자산, 부동산, 동산, 기타 실물 자산, 보험 자산)',
    Amount BIGINT(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '금액',
    MonetaryUnit varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '화폐 단위 (KRW, USD, ETC)',
    Created DATETIME(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '생성일',
    Updated DATETIME(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '업데이트일',
    Note varchar(255) NULL COMMENT '비고',
    Reserved0 varchar(100) NULL,
    Reserved1 varchar(100) NULL,
    Reserved2 varchar(100) NULL,
    Reserved3 varchar(100) NULL,
    Reserved4 varchar(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Email, ProductName),
    KEY Asset_FK (Email),
    CONSTRAINT Asset_FK FOREIGN KEY (Email) REFERENCES Account(Email)
    )
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```